# Should I use Spring Security module in a small application just for bcrypt hashing password?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, bcrypt

I'm creating a small web API using Spring Boot 2.3.1 with Spring Data and a few other minor packages. The project is simply an authentication microservice. I'll try to simplify things to focus on the problem.

Let's assume the application will have an entity `User` (username, password), `UserRepository`, `AuthenticationService`, and `AuthenticationController` with endpoints `/register` and `/authenticate` which handles POST-request with a username and password `{"username": "Bob", "password": "pass"}` also exists a postgres database with a table `users` with columns `username varchar(16)` & `password varchar(60)` and it will store usernames and password-hashes.

The goal of `/authenticate` endpoint is to return `true` if the user exists and password matches or otherwise `false`.

I'm not sure whether Spring Security is a best-case solution for such small functionality, maybe I should use simply some package that implements Bcrypt-hashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

including and configuring the spring security to the project can sometimes cause a lot of problems to your existing functionality. In this case in my opinion, you are better off without it. Keep it Simple, if at a later point something like URL filtering and advanced navigation permissions come in think about it.